# Vue.js @click doesnt work in option on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a dropdown of options that when one otion is clicked it sets "Value" in vue to a specified ammount. Then I dispaly the selected ammount in an input. Example:

```html
<select class="form-control" style="max-width: 150px;">
  <option value="hideMe" selected="true" disabled="disabled" >Select value...</option>
  <option  value="10" @click="Value = 10">Buy 10</option>
  <option  value="20" @click="Value = 20">Buy 20</option>
  <option  value="50" @click="Value = 50">Buy 50</option>
  <option  value="100" @click="Value = 100">Buy 100</option>
  <option  value="500" @click="Value = 500">Buy 500</option>
  <option  value="1000" @click="Value = 1000">Buy 1000</option>
</select>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="ammount" v-model="Value" name="Amount">
```

It all works on my desktop but when I test it on my phone (android) it won't work. I use another vue to calculate the value of "Value" and that works on mobile and desktop.

What can I do for it to work on both mobile and desktop?

Comment: You have to listen to the `change` event to get informed if the selected options changed. Why do you want to solve that with with `click` events?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>use @click.native="value = 100".</strike> (only working with components)

But better way is to use v-model on select and not define @click on options.

Comment: Not all browser fire `click` events on an `option` element. You should assume, that this is not the case at all.

Comment: You should explain why you think that adding `.native` will help in that case. The `.native` is for components not for regular html elements.

Comment: Thank you, I used the v-model option since you said its better and it worked!

Comment: Thank you for correction. Edit my answer if you wish.